# How to capture onChange event from a field with object type State

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, onchange

I am unable to capture the onChange event from a Obect which contains multiple object fields in itself.

Here is my useState hook.

```
    const [train, setTrain] = useState({
    trainNumber: "",
    trainName: "",
    fromStation: "",
    toStation: "",
    departureDateTime: "",
    arrivalDateTime: "",
//unable to capture travelDetails property changes.
    travelDetails: {   
      coachesClass: [
        {
          availableTickets: "",
          travelClass: "",
          fare: "",
        },
      ],
    },
  });
```

Suppose I want to check the onChange event for travelDetails.coachesClass[0].availableTickets then how to do that?

```
        <div className="row">
          <label htmlFor="availableTickets">First AC</label>
          <div className="col-4">
            <input
              type="number"
              name="availableTickets"
              className="form-control"
              placeholder="Available Tickets"
              required
              value={train.travelDetails.coachesClass[0].availableTickets}
              onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
            />
          </div>
```

Here is the onChangeHandler

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
const { name, value } = e.target;
setTrain((prevState) => {
  return {
    ...prevState,
    [name]: value,
  };
});
```

};

It is working fine for other fields but inside travelDetails it is not capturing changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you are updating state will need to be adjusted since you are trying to update a property in an array nested within an object. Try something like this:

```
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setTrain((prevState) => {
      const newCoachesClass = [...prevState.travelDetails.coachesClass];
      newCoachesClass[0] = {
        ...prevState.travelDetails.coachesClass[0],
        availableTickets: e.target.value
      };
      return {
        ...prevState,
        travelDetails: {
          ...prevState.travelDetails,
          coachesClass: newCoachesClass
        }
      };
    });
  };
```

Also since your `input` is of `number` type, you probably want to initialize `availableTickets` to a number instead of a string:

```
const [train, setTrain] = useState({
    trainNumber: "",
    trainName: "",
    fromStation: "",
    toStation: "",
    departureDateTime: "",
    arrivalDateTime: "",
    travelDetails: {   
      coachesClass: [
        {
          availableTickets: 0,
    ...
```

Check out this codepen for an example: [image: Edit React-Update-Nested-State-Array]

Comment: Thank you so much. this is working perfectly and now I am able to capture the changes on other input field as well.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, your setState adds a new property on the state's object itself. Since it looks like you want that information to update your nested state, see updated snippet below:

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
const { name, value } = e.target;
  setTrain((prevState) => {
      return {
        ...prevState,
        travelDetails: {
          ...prevState.travelDetails,
          coachesClass: [
            {
              ...prevState.travelDetails.coachesClass[0],
              [name]: value
            }
          ]
        }
      };
    });
```

Comment: but this will break  on change event for other input boxes

Comment: sounds like you need to consider changing your state shape or adding additional handlers

Comment: @Hyetigran can i ask why you use prevstate and don't update directly like setTrain({...train, train.travelDetails.coachesClass[0][name]: value,}) ? im curious if it has some added benefit doing it your way

Comment: @NicholasAponte I updated OP's code and kept what wasn't broken the same. Otherwise, your example works well too. Generally, you want to use prevState when new state relies on values from prevState. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates